# XSL - Multiply the value of "space-after" attribute with a parameter

Tags: xslt

I would like to have a different value for "space after" depending on the value of a parameter

Here are parts of my xsl:

```
<xsl:param name="OFFSET_LEFT" select="2"/>

<xsl:call-template name="table_left">
   <xsl:with-param name="OFFSET_LEFT" select="$OFFSET_LEFT"/>
</xsl:call-template>


<xsl:template name="table_left">
   <xsl:param name="OFFSET_LEFT" select="1"/>

   <fo:block space-after="10.9mm" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
      &#0160;
   </fo:block>
```

so basically what I'm trying to do is change the line

```
<fo:block space-after="10.9mm" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
```

to

```
<fo:block space-after="(10.9 * $OFFSET_LEFT)mm" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
```

but this gives me an error:

```
Invalid property value encountered in space-after="(10.9 * $OFFSET_LEFT)mm": org.apache.fop.fo.expr.PropertyException: illegal character; property:'space-after'
```

So, I guess you see what I'm trying to do.
Is there any other way I could solve my problem

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
<fo:block space-after="{(10.9 * $OFFSET_LEFT)}mm" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
```